# How do I create a hoc for lazy load in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx, react-tsx

This is my first time writing React with Typescript. When I call app.tsx, an error pop up, what's wrong with this program

Error
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Module]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
// Lazy loading hoc 

import React from 'react'; 
const Lazy:React.FC = (func: Function) => {
  
  return (props: Props) => {
    const [compState, setCompState] = useState<{ comp: React.ReactNode }>({
        comp: <div style={styles}>loading...</div>,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const a = async () => {
            let c: React.ReactChild = await ComponentFunc();    
            setCompState({
                comp: c as React.ReactNode
            });
        };

        a();
    }, []);

    // return <>{compState.comp}</>;
    const Comp:React.ReactNode = compState.comp;
    return <>
        {Comp}
    </>
  }
}
```

```js
// myComponent
import React from 'react'; 
const myComponent:React.FC = () => {
  return <h1>my Component</h1>
}
export default myComponent;
```

```js
// app.tsx
import Lazy from './Lazy'; 
const component = Lazy(()=>import('./myComponent'));
const app:React.FC = () => {
  return <component />
}
export default app;
```

Comment: You not using `func` at all, and what is `ComponentFunc`?

Comment: I think that you load a module, why you don't use React.lazy? Do you want to have dynamic plugins?

Comment: You are right, I modify my program before I post, forgot changing that ComponentFunc. That's the Func. It doesn't work, what did I do wrong

Comment: not using React.lazy was because I wanna figure out how to write hoc with Typescript lol